# Noetherian Ring where all primes are maximal

Tags: ring-theory

I am trying to show that a commutative noetherian ring where all prime ideals are maximal is artinian.

I know that every ideal contains a finite product of primes and also as all primes are maximal we have that $Kdim=0$

I think that I should be able to use that every ideal contains a  finite product of primes to do something but I am unsure?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you're not including the zero ideal as maximal, the integers are a counter example. $(2)\supset(4)\supset(8)\supset\cdots$. If the zero ideal is maximal, you are in a field, and this is trivially artinian.

Comment: @Bryan What do you mean? The zero ideal of $\mathbf Z$ is not maximal, so of course it is not "included as maximal". The ring $\mathbf Z$ does not satisfy the requirement of the proposition. Moreover the zero ideal is not necessarily prime.

Comment: hmmmmm, this is a standard result whose proof can be found for instance in Atiyah & MacDonald

Comment: @BrunoJoyal you are right. The zero ideal is prime only if we are in an integral domain.

Comment: @Bryan That's right. As you point out, an integral domain which is artinian is a field. The interesting Artin rings are not domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I would post the solution that I now have (which I think is essentially just what is said in comments/ answer above) for completeness.

We will use the following three results.

> If we have the following short exact sequence:
>
> $0\xrightarrow{\ \ \ } M_1 \xrightarrow {\ \alpha \ } M_2 \xrightarrow{\ \beta\ } M_3 \xrightarrow{\ \ \ } 0$ of $R$ modules then if $M_2$ is artinian then so are $M_1$ and $M_3$

To see this we just note that if we had a chain that did not terminate in $M_1$ then its image under $\alpha$ would not terminate in $M_2$ ( as $\alpha$ is injective) similarly if we had a non-terminating decending chain in $M_3$ then we could just lift it back to $M_2$ via $\beta^{-1}$. Both of these lead to a contradiction and hence result.

> If $R$ is Artinian and $M$ is a f.g. $R$ module then $M$ is Artinian

To see this we note that if $R$ is artinian then so is $R^n$ and so for any f.g. module $M=x_1R+\ldots +x_nR$ we have the following short exact sequence:

$$0\xrightarrow{\ \ \ } Ker \xrightarrow{\ \ \ } R^n\xrightarrow{\ \ \ } M \xrightarrow {\ \ \ }0$$

and so from above $M$ is artinian.

> Let $R$ be a ring with ACC on two sided ideals. Let $I\neq R$ be an ideal of $R$. Show that >there exists prime ideals $P_1,\ldots , P_n$ such that $P_1\ldots P_n\subset I$

Let $\mathcal{F}=\{L\lhd R| \mbox{L does not contain a product of primes}\}$. Then each chain has a max element by the ACC condition and so from Zorn's Lemma we have that this family has a max element. Denote it as $M$.

Now as $M$ is not prime (else it would not be in $\mathcal{F}$) we have that there exists two ideals $A,B\lhd R$ such that $AB\not\lhd M$ but $AB\lhd M$

This then gives that $M\subset (A+M)$ and $M\subset (B+M)$ so that both $(A+M)$ and $(B+M)$ are not in $\mathcal{F}$, which means that they contain a product of primes

However from the above condition we have that $(A+M)(B+M)=AB+AM+MB+M^2\subseteq M$ and as from above we have that $(A+M)(B+M)$ contains a product of primes so does $M$ hence the family $\mathcal{F}$ is empty and we are done.

> Showing that $R$ is Artinian.

From above we know that there exists $P_1\ldots P_n=0$ and so we have the following sequence:

$$0=P_1\ldots P_n \subseteq P_1\ldots P_{n-1} \subseteq \ldots \subseteq P_1\subseteq R$$

Now as each $P_i$ is maximal we have that $R/P_i$ is a field and hence it is Artinian.

We also have that $P_1\ldots P_j/P_1\ldots P_jP_{j+1}$ is finitley generated (as $R$ is Noetherian) and has the natural module structure over $R/P_{j+1}$ and hence from above it is Artinian.

We then move up the chain noting that at each stage $P_1\ldots P_j/P_1\ldots P_jP_{j+1}$ is Artinian and $P_1\ldots P_{j+1}$ is artinian (from the previous step) and so $P_1\ldots P_J$ is artinian.

Then we have that $P_1$ is artinian and $R/P_1$ is artinian and hence $R$ is Artinian as required.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be the ring.

*Proof:* (which isn't too long, but is too high powered)

- Looking at a minimal primary decomposition of $\{0\}$, we find there are finitely many minimal primes of $R$, and these are maximal. Hence there are only finitely many maximal ideals, and $R$ is [semilocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-local_ring).
- since maximals=primes, the Jacobson radical and nilradical coincide.
- By Levitzky's theorem, the Jacobson radical is nilpotent, so the ring is [semiprimary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprimary_ring)
- By the [Hopkins-Levitzki theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprimary_ring), $R$ is Artinian.

---

You mentioned this:

> *I think that I should be able to use that every ideal contains a finite product of primes to do something but I am unsure?*

That is essentially a piece of the puzzle for some formulation of Hopkins-Levitzki, where you need that $\{0\}$ is a finite product of prime ideals. This is the approach you can find in Atiyah-Macdonald where they give another proof in theorem 8.5. It's a little harder to write out, and already well-written there, so I think I will not duplicate their work.

Comment: Thanks. I have not studied the Hopkins-Levitzki theorem but I will have a look. I have posted my solution below using only what I know , which from a quick look is how it is done in Atiyah-Macdonald, for completeness. I have still excepted your answer though. Thanks!